# Apply Excel's HYPERLINK function to each cell in a spilled range

Tags: excel

When the format of the cell is "=VLOOKUP(FILTER(returns spilled range of ids), table the ids come from, index, FALSE)", I get the hyperlink text associated with each id, but, when I wrap all of that in the HYPERLINK function, all the hyperlinks direct to the first text instead of a unique link for each cell in the spilled range.

I did a work around by making the next column create the hyperlinks instead and hid the non-functional link text's column, but that feels clumsy.

Comment: `HYPERLINK()` function will not work with `Spilled Range` it will always return the top most value not the following one. Can you do it without the `FILTER()` function to return the output? If so then it should work. Also will it be possible to post some sample data?